# How to access a Django rest Framework API from React

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I started to use django recently and I also tried to use React js and I wanted to do something simple like a nav var in React. I have accounts and log in implemented using django forms which work well. For the nav I would need to fetch the user information which I have on a DRF API as follows in the views file:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@authentication_classes((SessionAuthentication, TokenAuthentication))
@ensure_csrf_cookie
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def user_details_view(request, *args, **kwargs): #REST API for detailing some basic info about the user that is using the system at the moment
    current_user = request.user
    id = current_user.id
    status = 200
    try:
        obj = CustomUser.objects.get(id=id)
        data = UserSerializer(obj)
        return Response(data.data, status=status)
    except:
        status = 404
        return Response(status=404)
        return Response(data.data, status=status)
```

The urls are set up and if I access it in the django server it works fine but when I try on react by:

```
function loadUserInfo(callback){
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const method = 'GET';
  const url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/userdetails/";
  const responseType = "json";
  xhr.responseType = responseType; // Let the xhr request know that its getting a json 
  xhr.open(method, url); //This opens the request with the method and url entered
  xhr.onload = function(){
    console.log("This is the response: ",xhr.response)
    callback(xhr.response, xhr.status)
  }
  xhr.onerror = function(){
    callback({"message":"The request was an error"}, 400)
  }
  xhr.send();//Trigger that request
}
```

I get:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/userdetails/ 403 (Forbidden)
This is the response:  {detail: 'Authentication credentials were not provided.'}
```

How can I make React access the data? I only need to have some minor components made by react and also have it so that if I open it on another browser I can log in with a different user. I have looked into many resources but they do not seem to work for my case. I am using the django server.

Comment: provide credentials

Comment: I created the log in part in django only  using their authentication tools. I am trying to access it on React which is running on another port. Django is on 8000 and React on 3000

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the auth token in your react app. The token is generated once you log in to your Django from react app, and then you need to pass that token along with the get method.

```
axios
  .get('http://www.exapmle.com', {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Token ${props.token}`,
    },
  })
```

or in your Django app set the permission class as any for that model, or remove IsAuthenticated from the permission class.

```
   permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

Comment: I removed the permission_classes and moved the try block outside and while in django the api seems to be working fine but when I try to access it from React I get `accounts.models.CustomUser.DoesNotExist: CustomUser matching query does not exist.`. Is there something wrong with how I made the api because not I get the server internal error

Comment: This seems to be a different issue.

Comment: Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: I actually put the id manually in the view and it seems to be pulling the data as it should with the exception that on the line xhr.send() it gives me an error of 404 not found